# Specify rebuild policy in makefile

Tags: makefile, pdf-generation

I have a folder scructure containing many latex documents. I assume that all `.tex` files can be build unless they are under a folder prefixed with `00-`:

```
./presentation/slide.tex                  → BUILD
./presentation/section/1-introduction.tex → BUILD
./presentation/00-assets/packages.tex     → DONT BUILD
```

my makefile is pretty simple:

```
CC := latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make

all: makefile
    @find -L . -not -path "*/.*" -not -path "*/00-*" -name "*.tex" -execdir $(MAKE) -f $(PWD)/makefile {} \;
%.tex:
    $(CC) $@
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't work as I don't know how to specify that the produce is `%.pdf` and that `%.tex` is the input file. I don't know how to specify that a source file has to be build if either the `.pdf` file doesn't exist or if the source file has been modified since the last build.

Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[latexmk 4.27a](http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/latexmk/versions.html) onwards has a `output-directory` option.

```
tex := latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make

texfiles != find -L . -not -path "*/.*" -not -path "*/00-*" -name "*.tex"

.PHONY: all

all: $(texfiles:.tex=.pdf)

%.pdf: %.tex
    $(tex) -output-directory $(@D) $<
```

Use `$(shell ...)` instead of `!=` if you are using an older version of make.

Comment: `-output-directory $(@D)` causes issues when resolving relative path. I found the `-cd` option much more usefull.
Thanks anyway for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do, but consider [the second rule of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) :

> Every non-.PHONY rule must update a file with the exact name of its target.

Well, it's not mandatory, it's just a really bad idea not to follow these rules, even more if you don't know what you're doing. If I understand Latex well enough, your .tex file is not the build output, it's the input, it should therefore not be the target, instead it should be the prerequisite of the target.

I'd recommend to modify your Makefile by removing the %.tex rule and replacing it by this :

```
%.pdf: %.tex
    $(CC) $^
```

Now I'm not sure how PDF generation from Latex works, but with this you will generate a pdf file for all the .tex files given. You just have to specify all your .tex files in your `all` target's prerequisites.